# Make a GitHub repo private from within R using the gh package

Tags: r, github-api

I manage a GitHub organization with many repositories.  I need to modify many existing repositories and change their privacy status to private from public.  I am using the gh package (https://github.com/r-lib/gh) to interface with the GitHub API from within R.

I have tried using the PATCH verb in the GitHub API. Below is the code I am trying to use, but I can't get anything working.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

```r
gh::gh("PATCH /user/repos", name = "my-new-repo-for-gh-testing", private = TRUE)
#> Error in gh_process_response(raw): 
#> GitHub API error (404): 404 Not Found
#> Message: Not Found
#> Read more at https://developer.github.com/v3
#> 
#> URL not found: https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I suggest filing an issue the with the package developer at https://github.com/r-lib/gh/issues.

Comment: I think the problem is my ignorance of the GitHub API, rather than anything wrong with the package. I will reach out to the package author if we can't figure it out here, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone reading this later, this is the line of code that ended up working.

```r
gh("PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo", 
   owner = "ddsjoberg", 
   repo = "my-new-repo-for-gh-testing", 
   private = TRUE)
```